# How to stack aggregate information in a dataframe based off two columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that has a column which has rows that I want to become their own columns and populate the each row with data from another column.

My starting dataframe is the following:

```
data = {'key':  ['AAAA-27293', 'AAAA-27293','AAAA-27293','AAAA-27293','AAAA-27293','AAAA-27293','AAAA-27293', 'BBBBB-27296','BBBBB-27296','BBBBB-27296','BBBBB-27296','BBBBB-27296','BBBBB-27296','BBBBB-27296'],

        'project_id': [ '105', '105','105','105','105','105','105', '107','107','107','107','107','107','107'],

        'create_date': [ '2019-01-02', '2019-01-02','2019-01-02','2019-01-02','2019-01-02','2019-01-02','2019-01-02', '2019-01-16','2019-01-16','2019-01-16','2019-01-16','2019-01-16','2019-01-16','2019-01-16'],

        'summary': ['Automated-email','Automated-email','Automated-email','Automated-email','Automated-email','Automated-email','Automated-email','Automated-email','Automated-email','Automated-email','Automated-email','Automated-email','Automated-email','Automated-email'],

        'description': [ 'Output', 'Output','Output','Output','Output','Output','Output','Output','Output','Output','Output','Output','Output','Output'],

        'field': [ 'issue', 'message reciever','message sender','checker','resolution','source','status','issue', 'message reciever','message sender','checker','resolution','source','status'],

        'field_value': ['task','johnsmith@yahoo','jim@gmail','None','rejected','ABC123','resolved', 'job','ian@yahoo','johnharris@aol','None','completed','ABC432','resolved'],
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['key','project_id','create_date','summary','description','field','field_value'])
```

You will see all the row values in every column are the same besides in columns 'field' and 'field_value'. The column 'field' has 7 unique values that I want to become their own column, and each row should populate with the values from 'field_value'.

The result I hope to reach is:

```
data2 = {'key':  ['AAAA-27293', 'BBBBB-27296'],

        'project_id': [ '105', '107'],

        'create_date': [ '2019-01-02','2019-01-16'],

        'summary': ['Automated-email','Automated-email'],

        'description': [ 'Output','Output'],

        'issue': ['task','job'],

        'message reciever': ['johnsmith@yahoo','ian@yahoo'],

        'message sender': ['jim@gmail','johnharris@aol'],

        'checker': ['None','None'],

        'resolution': ['rejected','completed'],

        'source': ['ABC123','ABC432'],

        'staus': ['resolved', 'resolved']
        }

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2,columns=['key','project_id','create_date','summary','description','issue','message reciever','message sender','checker','resolution','source','status'])
```

I have tried the below piece of code which resulted in an error

```
df.set_index(['key','project_id','create_date','summary','description','field','field_value'],drop=True).unstack('field_value')
```

Comment: _I have tried the below piece of code which resulted in an error_ What error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, do not add field_value into the index and use unstack without paramters to unstack the intermost index level, which is 'field':

```
df.set_index(['key','project_id',
              'create_date','summary',
              'description', 'field'])['field_value'].unstack().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
|    | key         |   project_id | create_date   | summary         | description   | checker   | issue   | message reciever   | message sender   | resolution   | source   | status   |
|---:|:------------|-------------:|:--------------|:----------------|:--------------|:----------|:--------|:-------------------|:-----------------|:-------------|:---------|:---------|
|  0 | AAAA-27293  |          105 | 2019-01-02    | Automated-email | Output        | None      | task    | johnsmith@yahoo    | jim@gmail        | rejected     | ABC123   | resolved |
|  1 | BBBBB-27296 |          107 | 2019-01-16    | Automated-email | Output        | None      | job     | ian@yahoo          | johnharris@aol   | completed    | ABC432   | resolved |
```

Comment: @muchappreciated Did this solution help you?